# How do I freeze on the last line of text and not repeat with this Typewriter effect?

Tags: javascript

Currently the animation begins to type out each line, deletes then moves on typing the next. Trying to freeze the animation after typing out the last line "Text Line 3" and stay as that. Which part of the code do I change to achieve that?

This typewriter effect uses JavaScript instead of CSS. Please help. Thank you!!!

```js
var _CONTENT = [ 
 "Text Line 1", 
 "Text Line 2", 
 "Text Line 3"
];

var _PART = 0;

var _PART_INDEX = 0;

var _INTERVAL_VAL;

var _ELEMENT = document.querySelector("#text");

var _CURSOR = document.querySelector("#cursor");

function Type() { 
 var text =  _CONTENT[_PART].substring(0, _PART_INDEX + 1);
 _ELEMENT.innerHTML = text;
 _PART_INDEX++;

   
 if(text === _CONTENT[_PART]) {
 
  _CURSOR.style.display = 'none';

  clearInterval(_INTERVAL_VAL);
  setTimeout(function() {
   _INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Delete, 50);
  }, 1000);
 }
}


function Delete() {
 
 var text =  _CONTENT[_PART].substring(0, _PART_INDEX - 1);
 _ELEMENT.innerHTML = text;
 _PART_INDEX--;


 if(text === '') {
  clearInterval(_INTERVAL_VAL);

  if(_PART == (_CONTENT.length - 1))
   _PART = 0;
  else
   _PART++;
  
  _PART_INDEX = 0;

  
  setTimeout(function() {
   _CURSOR.style.display = 'inline-block';
   _INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Type, 100);
  }, 200);
 }
}

 
_INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Type, 100);
```

```css
#container {
 text-align: center;
}

#text {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 color: orange;
 letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#cursor {
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 3px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: blue;
 animation: blink .75s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
 from, to { 
  background-color: transparent 
 }
 50% { 
  background-color: blue; 
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
 <div id="text"></div><div id="cursor"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not a service to get 3rd-party scripts fixed or modified for you. (This appears to be lifted from https://usefulangle.com/post/75/typing-effect-animation-javascript-css, or a similar source.) Please explain what _you_ have tried so far, in order to achieve this. Have you made an effort to analyze & understand how this script basically works?

Comment: I learned some HTML and CSS myself but been trying to incorporate some js. Been trying to figure this out for some time and playing around with the code. I just copied this example from that website since it's similar to what I am doing (my own code is a bit unorganised and might be messy to understand). Done a lot of research but can't seem to find an answer so made this post hoping for more specific and targeted solution. Would appreciate any help and tips.

Comment: I'd suggest you post your code. It's not likely that the error (if there is one) in your code is also in a "similar" piece of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the `Delete` function, this line is used to check if the array index, `_PART`, needs to “wrap around”, to start the whole thing with the first text again on the next iteration:

```
if(_PART == (_CONTENT.length - 1))
```

So you can easily use that same check (just negated) inside `Type` function, to only schedule the next `Delete` call, if we are not currently at the last part already.

```js
var _CONTENT = [
  "Text Line 1",
  "Text Line 2",
  "Text Line 3"
];

var _PART = 0;

var _PART_INDEX = 0;

var _INTERVAL_VAL;

var _ELEMENT = document.querySelector("#text");

var _CURSOR = document.querySelector("#cursor");

function Type() {
  var text = _CONTENT[_PART].substring(0, _PART_INDEX + 1);
  _ELEMENT.innerHTML = text;
  _PART_INDEX++;


  if (text === _CONTENT[_PART]) {

    //_CURSOR.style.display = 'none';

    clearInterval(_INTERVAL_VAL);
    
    // added check here - only schedule Delete function call,
    // if this was NOT the last text part
    if (_PART != (_CONTENT.length - 1))
      setTimeout(function() {
        _INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Delete, 50);
      }, 1000);
  }
}


function Delete() {

  var text = _CONTENT[_PART].substring(0, _PART_INDEX - 1);
  _ELEMENT.innerHTML = text;
  _PART_INDEX--;


  if (text === '') {
    clearInterval(_INTERVAL_VAL);

    if (_PART == (_CONTENT.length - 1))
      _PART = 0;
    else
      _PART++;

    _PART_INDEX = 0;


    setTimeout(function() {
      _CURSOR.style.display = 'inline-block';
      _INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Type, 100);
    }, 200);
  }
}


_INTERVAL_VAL = setInterval(Type, 100);
```

```css
#container {
  text-align: center;
}

#text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: orange;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}

#cursor {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 3px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
  animation: blink .75s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  from,
  to {
    background-color: transparent
  }
  50% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="text"></div>
  <div id="cursor"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you so much! Is there any way to have the cursor to continue blinking after the last line is typed out and pauses there?

Comment: @Celine sure, just remove/comment out the line that hides it, `_CURSOR.style.display = 'none';`

Comment: I did remove it and it shows a static straight line. But possible to have it blink? Like show for one second, hide the next, and show again etc? Thank you!!

Comment: I made the mentioned change in the above snippet, and it keeps on blinking, as expected - at least when I am testing this in Chrome. (And there is nothing apparent on a quick look, why it should not work the same way in other browsers.)